# Rails Amazon S3 authorizing private files using presigned urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following problem,

In my rails 4 app I am hosting images / videos on s3. Currently I made all the files public and for example an image I can access by storing the public link in the database.

However, I want some of the images videos to be private.

I looked at the presigned url options using the following

```
s3 =  Aws::S3::Client.new(
        region: AWS_REGION, 
        access_key_id: S3_CONFIG['access_key_id'],
        secret_access_key: S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']
 )
resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3)   
bucket = resource.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
utilities = bucket.objects(prefix: '/folder').each do |obj|
       obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 3600).to_s
end
```

This works fine, but how would I use the presigned url since I can obviously not store them in the db like the public links.

I am using aws-sdk version 2

I am also wondering if this in general is a good solution?

Thanks for any hints,
Jean

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Presigner Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html)

Example:

```
signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
url = signer.presigned_url(:put_object, bucket: "bucket", key: "path")
```